# How to initialize a value in a variable in a retrofit function?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

```
class postFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var binding : FragmentBoardFreepostBinding
    val bundle = Bundle()
    val items = ArrayList<Contents>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = PostBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        runBlocking { 
            launch { 
                getPosts("LATEST", 0)
            }
            launch { 
                Log.d("items", items.toString())
            }
        }
        
        ...

        return binding.root
    }

    fun getPosts(sortType : String, page :Int) {
        val authService = getRetrofit().create(AuthRetrofitInterface::class.java)

        authService.getPosts(sortType, page).enqueue(object : Callback<PostsResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<PostsResponse>,
                response: Response<PostsResponse>
            ) {
                when (response.code()) {
                    200 -> {
                        Log.d("posts/SUCCESS", response.toString())
                        Log.d("posts/resp", response.body().toString())

                        var post = response.body()!!
                        items = post.content as ArrayList<Contents>
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Log.d("posts/FAILURE", response.toString())
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<PostsResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("posts/fail in onFailure", t.toString())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I initialized the items variable in the getpost function. However, when viewed through log, items are always [].

How can I initialize the items variable with the content of response.body?

I change so many things, but I couldnt solve this problem

1. ArrayList -> List
2. Declare "items" as global variable

Comment: Were you able to check the data in `onResponse()` function? (from `Log.d("posts/SUCCESS", response.toString())` this code)

Comment: The value is well put in there